# Return Multiple strings of hash

Tags: c#, asp.net, md5

I have the following function:

```
public string GetRaumImageName()
    {
         var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
        byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Michael"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

This works fine with just one value.

Now i want to encrypt multiple values. I tried something:

```
public string GetRaumImageName()
    {
        var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] hash = new byte[0];

        foreach (PanelView panelView in pv)
        {
            hash = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(panelView.Title));

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));

        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

But only the last Value in the list in getting encrypt. How can i encrypt multiples values which are in a list and return them?

Comment: Can you return an `IEnumerable<String>` instead of just one `String`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public IEnumerable<String> GetRaumImageName()
    {
        var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();

        byte[] hash = new byte[0];

        foreach (PanelView panelView in pv)
        {
            hash = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(panelView.Title));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));

            }
            yield return sb.ToString();
        }          
    }
```

This will return all the `Values` u need as `IEnumerable<String>`

Typical usage

```
var values = GetRaumImageName();
foreach(value in values)
{
    // use the 'value'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add every hash to a list, then return that list:

```
public List<string> GetRaumImageName()
{
    var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    List<string> hashes = new List<string>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] hash = new byte[0];

    foreach (PanelView panelView in pv)
    {
        hash = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(panelView.Title));

        //clear sb
        sb.Remove(0, sb.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
        }
        hashes.Add(sb.ToString());
    }
    return hashes;
}
```